# get php DateInterval in total 'minutes'

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get the PHP "DateInterval" value in "total minutes" value. How to get it? Seems like simple format("%i minutes") not working?

Here is the sample code:

```
$test = new \DateTime("48 hours");
$interval = $test->diff(new \DateTime());
```

Now if I try to get the interval in total days, its fine:

```
echo $interval->format('%a total days');
```

It is showing 2 days as output, which is totally fine. What I am trying to get if to get the value in "total minutes", so I tried:

```
echo $interval->format('%i total minutes');
```

Which is not working. Any help appreciated to get my desired output.

Comment: Can you show some more actual code? E.g. initialisation, usage, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's possible as a general rule. What if the interval is 'one month'?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: The most sense would make to subtract two UNIX timestamps and divide by 60. The `DateInterval` class is unnecessary here (and apparently not able to handle this).

Comment: As there is always 1440 minutes in one day, why don't you simply multiply ?

Comment: @Brewal - Well, not really. A day can normally have between 23 and 25 hours. Daylight saving time.

Comment: So deceze's solution looks good

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
abs((new \DateTime("48 hours"))->getTimestamp() - (new \DateTime)->getTimestamp()) / 60
```

That's the easiest way to get the difference in minutes between two `DateTime` instances.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out too with deceze's comment. Thanks for posting the complete solution.

Comment: Yeah, that deceze guy, he's great... ;o)

Comment: I missed that it was you :D

Comment: Gives incorrect results when the date period is across DST switchover

Comment: @Lenin Define "incorrect". It works as expected here: https://3v4l.org/9ZGuo

Comment: @deceze Apologies. It does work. But I don't know how because timestamp is in epoch which doesn't understand DST.

Comment: @Lenin In my example above, when the clock jumps forward from 1:59:59 to 3:00:00, exactly 1 second has elapsed, which is what the UNIX timestamp models.

Answer (score 31):

If you are stuck in a position where all you have is the `DateInterval`, and you (like me) discover that there seems to be no way to get the total minutes, seconds or whatever of the interval, the solution is to create a DateTime at zero time, add the interval to it, and then get the resulting timestamp:

```
$timeInterval      = //the DateInterval you have;
$intervalInSeconds = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp(0)->add($timeInterval)->getTimeStamp();
$intervalInMinutes = $intervalInSeconds/60; // and so on
```

Comment: This makes the calculation really robust. Works for all valid php DateInterval values.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote two functions that just calculates the totalTime from a DateInterval.
Accuracy can be increased by considering years and months.

```
function getTotalMinutes(DateInterval $int){
    return ($int->d * 24 * 60) + ($int->h * 60) + $int->i;
}

function getTotalHours(DateInterval $int){
    return ($int->d * 24) + $int->h + $int->i / 60;
}
```

Comment: You can use `$int->days * 24` to include the preceding months or years in the calculation.

Comment: If the `DateInterval` is a result of a `DateTimeInterface->diff()` you should indeed always simply replave `$int->d` by `$int->days`. However if it is  not, `$int->days` is `undefined`! Then there seems to be no straightforward way within the the `DateTimeInterface` class to achieve this!

Comment: Add `+ ($int->s>=30 ? 1 : 0)` to round up half a minute to one minute so that a time difference of 3:55 minute becomes 4 instead of 3.

Comment: This does not distinguish positive and negative intervals.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the excepted answer as a method in PHP7.2 style:

```
public static function getMinutesDifference(\DateTime $a, \DateTime $b): int
{
    return abs($a->getTimestamp() - $b->getTimestamp()) / 60;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That works perfectly.

```
function calculateMinutes(DateInterval $int){
    $days = $int->format('%a');
    return ($days * 24 * 60) + ($int->h * 60) + $int->i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is about minutes but **if you want to recalculate every carry over points** (like I needed to) you can use this solution suggested by [@glavic in the comments on the php.net man page](https://www.php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.format.php#113204) (simplified and turned into a function):

```php
private function calculateCarryOverPoints(\DateInterval $dateInterval): \DateInterval
{
    $from = new \DateTime;
    $to = clone $from;
    // Add time of dateInterval to empty DateTime object
    $to = $to->add($dateInterval);
    // Calculate difference between zero DateTime and DateTime with added DateInterval time
    // Which returns a DateInterval object $diff with correct carry over points (days, hours, minutes, seconds etc.)
    return $from->diff($to);
}
```