# PHP: Get difference between two DateTime objects in Hours, Minutes, and Seconds

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the number of hours a person has worked on a given day. To do so, I need to get the difference between two DateTime objects in Hours, Minutes, and Seconds. So far I can successfully do so like this

```
        $timeIn        = new DateTime($time['timeIn']);
        $timeOut       = new DateTime($time['timeOut']);
        $time['hours'] = date_diff($timeIn, $timeOut) -> format("%H:%i:%s");
```

This seems to work fine, until I put in a test case where the employee forgot to clock out. Now, let's say that

```
$timeIn  = '2016-09-28 14:26:17'
$timeOut = '2016-09-30 09:53:53'
```

In that case, the difference SHOULD be 43:27:36 (Because there is over a day in between the timeIn and timeOut). Instead, I get 19:27:36 (as if it's just truncating the days off and returning the rest). How can I add that day onto the hours instead of truncating it? (I'm looking to get 43:27:36, NOT 1day, 19 hours, ect ect. So I'm trying to get the answer in HH:MM:SS)

Comment: You have to do the calculations manually. This explains how to do it in minutes which isn't too far away from what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776061/get-php-dateinterval-in-total-minutes

Comment: For a clearer explanation of the question so you get better answers:
Do you only want to have `HH:MM:SS` or are you ok with prefixing the days before hand? as in `DD HH:MM:SS`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Scott suggested but with a tweak, we'll need to format this ourselves, but we have nifty `sprintf` to help:

```
$start = new \DateTime("2016-09-28 14:26:17");
$end   = new \DateTime("2016-09-30 09:53:53");

$interval = $end->diff($start);

$time = sprintf(
    '%d:%02d:%02d',
    ($interval->d * 24) + $interval->h,
    $interval->i,
    $interval->s
);
```

Comment: Holy Sh*t on a shingle I never would have thought of this. It's...beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, it can be made into a one liner, just sharing like this so it's easier to read.

Comment: I prefer readability over line numbers ;) It's perfect just the way it is.

Comment: The only problem, is it wont work over a month. Might be worth changing to using `$interval->days * 24` instead... just in case someone forgets to logout and goes away on holiday.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure what the difference is. Lemme look through the interval docs real quick. BRB...

Comment: `->d` will be a max of 31, as it'll roll over to months and reset, `->days` will always be the total number of days

Comment: Ok. I see what you are saying. I wonder what would happen if $interval-> days returns false... I'm going to play with it a bit... EDIT: Nothing bad happens when $interval->days returns false. It works perfectly either way. Thanks again @R. Chappell

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using the `\DateTime` objects - although there shouldn't be much of a difference in the end `date_diff` is just an alias of `\DateTime::diff`.

You want to check the number of days in the `DateInterval` object;

```
$start = new \DateTime("2016-09-28 14:26:17");
$end = new \DateTime("2016-09-30 09:53:53");

$interval = $end->diff($start);

$days = $interval->d;
if ($days > 0) {
    echo $interval->format("%a %h:%i:%s\n");
} else {
    echo $interval->format("%h:%i:%s\n");
}
```

Comment: This would work, but it's not what I'm asking in the original question. (+1 anyways for the help) I need to convert that number of days to hours (multiply by 24) AND add it to the number of hours that was returned by date_diff(). Any ideas?

Comment: Please be aware that when using `[interval]->format()` the characters used to format the output vary from the common usage when formatting regular dates. E.g. if you want leading zeros, use `%H:%I:%S`.

Answer (score 1):

`date_diff()` returns a DateInterval instance. Look at [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method or [DateInterval::days](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days) field. Hour, minute and second values refer to the remainder in the last day (if more than one). You are looking for `a` the total number of days.

```
$timeIn        = new DateTime($time['timeIn']);
$timeOut       = new DateTime($time['timeOut']);
$diff          = date_diff($timeIn, $timeOut) -> format("%H:%i:%s");
$days          = $diff->days;
$time['hours'] = // calculate based on days + remainder...
```

Comment: this is nice and elegant. I like it. But how can I multiply the days by 24, and then add it onto the hours? It seems like this is getting very complicated...