# Find date_diff in minutes?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Can `date_diff` be used to compute difference in minutes?

```
$a   = date_create('2016-11-03 00:00:00');
$b   = date_create('2016-11-05 00:19:00');

$dd = date_diff($a, $b);
echo $dd->format('%i');
```

The above code will return `19 minutes` even if it's already been `2 days`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get php DateInterval in total 'minutes'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776061/get-php-dateinterval-in-total-minutes)

Comment: date_diff will return the DateInterval object. You can't get complete time in minutes with that. If really want complete minutes build a own logic to calculate that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time difference in minutes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this**

it will output difference in minutes.

```
$a = new DateTime('2016-11-05 00:00:00');
$b = new DateTime('2016-11-05 00:19:00');
 $diff =  ($b->getTimestamp() - $a->getTimestamp())/60;
 echo $diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime()`
Get difference in **hour**,**minute**, and **seconds**

```
$a =   new \DateTime("2016-11-05 00:00:00");
$b =   new \DateTime("2016-11-05 00:19:00");

$dateinterval = $b->diff($a);

$time = sprintf(
    '%d:%02d:%02d',
    ($dateinterval->d * 24) + $dateinterval->h,
    $dateinterval->i,
    $dateinterval->s
);
```