# Set Condition using timespan Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I want to set condition that once the post is already posted 30mins up will not able to edit or customize.

My timespan codes:

```
<?php 
$post_date = $threads['created_at'];
$now = time();
echo timespan($post_date, $now, 1). '&nbsp'.lang_key('ago') ?>
```

I want to have a condition something like this:

***Note this code is a sample only.***

```
<?php if(timespan >= '30 mins'){
//disable the edit button
}else{
//enable the edit button
} ?>
```

Comment: [Here's a way to get the difference between two `datetime`s in minutes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776407/3585500)

Comment: No not that once sir... want I want is that the edit button will be disable once it is posted more than 30 mins!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a well formed timestamp you can do:

```
    if (strtotime($threads['created_at']) < strtotime("-30 minutes")) {
        echo ' is older than 30 mins';
    } else {
        echo ' is not older than 30 mins';
    }
```

Comment: I am away from computer atm i will try this codes later on btw way thank you in advance